# Redirect to a 3rd party HTTP page from HTTPS without the certificate error

Tags: java, jsp, security, https, warnings

We have a web application. Our homepage is in HTTPS. When a user clicks a link to go to the content provider's website (where HTTPS is not yet enabled), we get the following error image. Any ideas to circumvent this?

Our view is a JSP which posts to the 3rd party.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO8nQ.png) to the error png.

Thanks in advance,
Karan Nanda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you find a way to circumvent this it (hopefully) will be only a shortlived solution: you would undermine a security measure.

Perhaps not implementing this in the foreground = browser but transferring this to the backend might help: have your JSP talk to some code on your server which transfers the data to the content providers site. But this heavily depends on what or why you POST your data.

Comment: Yes, we're looking for a short term solution. The reasoning for this is that users in production should not back down from entering the 3rd party website. This will be in place till the 3rd party site is HTTPS compliant.